# keep past value of variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I put a variable (price) to a html form from database.
then user changes the price and submit the form and variable is updated in database.
I want to keep previous value (last state and show it in the form) but if I update the form variable keeps updating.

What is best way to remember previous value of variable (in array for example) ?

Comment: How long do you want to remember the previous value?

Comment: user may change price till he is ok with it. he/she should see initial amount.
I can just make one column with initial price and keep it unchanged.
still How can i show last value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're updating this data in an actual Database, you should create a parallel table that holds the value of the previous row.

Otherwise, if you're updating only an array, you can just create a copy prior to updating the array: http://codepad.org/SvlasJ7f

```
<?php

    $array = array('Old Value');
    $lastarray = '';

    updateArray($array,'New Value');

    function updateArray(&$a,$v) {
        $GLOBALS[lastarray] = $a;
        $a = array($v);
    }
?>
```

Comment: I made a parallel column next to actual column. I will try to make array and every time to push new values (as key - value) to the beginning (or end ) of an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the LAST value AND display it on the screen, combine the two! Just display the previous value, in a `readonly` `input` field in your form. That way, you will still have the previous value every time the form is submitted.

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="Current" value="...">
    <input type="text" name="Last"    value="..." readonly="readonly">
</form>
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: but I get value of variable from database so If I update it it in the form it gets updated in db and consequently in html. But solution I did is to make two columns (static and changing) and get value of original from static column. Anyway - I wanted to make array of changin values - so every change is remembered - i have think over this problem :)

Comment: You want to update it to the DB EVERY time that the user changes it? Why not only when they are DONE? You said in a comment "user may change price till he is ok with it". So only save the value when OK. That will save you a LOT of queries to the DB.

Comment: every time they change it and press button it is written to database. if they are ok with it they make no change. system doesn't know when they are done - or it is ok every time.. I'd have to try work on it more